# the word that i used to refer myself is it the correct word or not?

Tags: meaning, adjectives

I was writing in my diary about how my day went and how I am as a person when it comes to do something and how i procrastinate.
I used the following words :

> "I am very lazy and detrimental to keep the spirit alive in me".

- Does this sentence mean anything?
- Correct me if i am wrong.
- Can "detrimental" word be used when describing someone's actions?
- if wrong,  what word can exactly be used instead of "detrimental"?

Comment: Note that 'I' is always a capital letter when referring to oneself.

Comment: Because you are right that detrimental describes actions, **I am detrimental** has no meaning. My laziness can be detrimental, though. Or as a joke, you can say your boss is detrimental to your health.

Comment: Why the tag Present tense?

Comment: because I'm referring in the present state

Answer (score 1):

The way we use *detrimental* in English, it licenses a prepositional phrase but not a verb phrase. Thus

> The loud music from the apartment upstairs is detrimental to **my studying**.

but not

> * The loud music from the apartment upstairs is detrimental to **prepare for the exam**.

Comment: thank you so much